# Wix installer not picking up the installation path

Tags: wix

I am completely new to `WIX` and just trying to debug an issue.
I have a text box for installation path but when user chooses a new installation directory, `WIX` doesn't pick it up and doesn't install it in that path.

What are the areas I should be even looking into?

Here is something in the Bundle I saw:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
  <Component Id="cmpOnlineSupport.url" Guid="{somethingHere}">
    <File Id="filOnlineSupport.url" Source="$(var.ResourcesDir)\Online Support.url" KeyPath="yes"/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Comment: This is already well-defined and supported behaviour, try looking at [Using WixUI_InstallDir](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_installdir.html)

Comment: I just wrote an answer that is vaguely related I think. Maybe check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48464105/129130. Or maybe I don't fully understand what you are asking. You say this is a bundle?