# WixUI_Mondo and WixUI_InstallDir

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

Is it possible to combine WixUI_Mondo and WixUI_InstallDir? I need a dialog where the user is able to change the destination folder then proceed to selecting instalation type. Please help, I am new to Wix toolset. Thanks!

Comment: Got this sorted?

Answer (score 1):

***Mondo***: I might be missing something essential you need here, but the Mondo dialog set does have a dialog like that - 3rd in sequence, select **`"Custom"`**. Maybe this is all you need?:

[image: Custom]

For the **`Browse...`** button to be work (not be grayed out) you must [**set the feature directory to be configurable**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48490880/129130). See that link - some way down the page - or minimal markup at the bottom here:

[image: Browse...]

```
<!-- A configurable directory feature -->
<Feature Id="MainApplication" Title="MainApplication" ConfigurableDirectory="MYCUSTOMDIR">
        <!-- your stuff here -->
</Feature>
```

And elsewhere in the WiX source, the actual configurable directory:

```
<Directory Id="MYCUSTOMDIR">
     <!-- Mock-up GUID that MUST be changed, custom target directories do not function with auto-GUIDs -->
     <Component Id="MyFile.exe" Guid="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" Feature="FeatureDirectory">
         <File Source="C:\SourceControl\MyFile.exe" />
     </Component>    
</Directory>
```