# How to make an installation (setup.exe) for our software with registration stuff during installation?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Im currently building a software in visual basic using vb.net programming. The software includes a login page. But right now the login username and password is hard coded into the coding. I want it to be so that user can register their own username and password during installation process (during setup.exe). How do I do this?

Comment: Instead of during installation, why not during first run?

Comment: I apologise for my noobness, but may I ask, what is a first run?

Comment: When the user starts your app for the first time (no username/password are registered yet): then ask to register. Else ask to login against stored credentials

Comment: Is there any tutorial I can look at online? For example, making one of the form on vb net only appearing once which is during initial setup. I dont see much tutorial on it unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WiX Toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/) that will allow you to create `.wixproj` installer project in .net. Then you can also take input during the installation. You can follow this nice [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713806/wix-setup-with-user-input) on `stackoverflow`