# How to enable 'Browse' option for msi installer using WIX

Tags: c#, .net, wix

I am trying to create a msi installer for my system application using wix. Now we have given an option for 'Browse' to user where they can chose a directory for their installation. But by default it is appearing disabled.

Can someone help me, how can I enable this 'Browse' option?

[image: MSI Installer image]

Comment: [Some sample WiX markup for this can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56276344/129130).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the "WixUI_Mondo"

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />
```

In this case, you could go on your main feature, and set the "ConfigurableDirectory" as follows

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MyApp" Level="1" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        ...
</Feature>
```

Below is what you should see:

[image]